# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 build very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I got a problem when upgrading a solution from VS2013 to VS2015. There is a project with quite a lot of files. The time for VS2015 to build it take up to 30 minutes. I know VS2015 use new feature called Roslyn to handle the build, using the process VBCSCompiler.exe.
Using ProcessMonitor to monitor this process, after the steps to read all the source files, I just see a lot of event Thread Create, Thread Exit. VS2015 Output still stucks at "Build Started: xxx.csproj". After about 30 minutes, the build is complete.

Can anyone knows what is the problem with Roslyn? Or is there anyway to temporary disable this feature?

Updated: The project is a Class Library, .NET 3.5. There is no Nuget. Image link below is the reference. (I cannot post image directly, lack of reputation)
https://postimg.cc/image/4mvl0ejbj/
This is the link for the build log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m14jglamhxhvygo/DTO_Build_Log.txt?dl=0

Comment: We'll need more info. What kind of programming languages, project types, are you using the Command Tool Runner to execute Node, grunt and others as part of the build? Is NuGet restore during build turned on? Have you tried running a diagnostics log for MsBuild to see in which detailed steps most time is consumed? Does it happen on other projects or just this one? Can you try to unload some projects in your solution to see if there is one that's causing it?

Comment: Please update your question with any information you can find, before that, we can't really help you.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I added more information about my project

Comment: ugh, `2625454 ms  Csc`... see if `/m /p:UseSharedCompilation=false` parameters for msbuild help

Comment: And that time is almost all taken up by the DTO project `DTO.csproj` what size in bytes are we talking about in this case, I've seen some datalayer projects with generated code into the magabyte range per single cs file...

Comment: @jessehouwing, the total size of that DTO project is around 130MB. All the files here are almost generated by a tool. Maybe the shared compilation can get problem with this case?

Comment: @m0sa, I added <UseSharedCompilation>false</UseSharedCompilation> to all project file. Now I see the csc.exe occupying the CPU, the build is still slow.

Comment: That's what I guessed. It's almost expected with 130 MB of sources. What target platform and optimization options are you using? It may be worth submitting a ticket on the Roslyn GitHub issues page.

Comment: also, try to skip .pdb generation if possible, I've seen this speed up the emit phase of the compilation a lot.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I have created this issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15887. Maybe I need to delay this upgrade for now.

Comment: I think VBCSCompiler is unlikely to be the problem here. The type of problems that can show up with it (in rare corner cases) don't really line up with the symptoms here. Given there is a 30 minute compilation time this is much more likely to simply be a problem with compiler itself. Is it possible for you to share out the project? Lacking that could you build locally, grab a trace with PerfView and share that out? Either of those would really help us identify what is going on here.

Comment: never use PerfView before, i will look at it and provide the trace asap.

Comment: @jessehouwing, target platform is AnyCPU, optimization is disabled. This is just a debug build.

Comment: Optimization in our case doesn't impact performance too much. At least not remotely to the level you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ticket for this issue is fixed, https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15887.
Hopefully it will be released in VS2017.